# Доступ к веб-интерфейсу решения myCompany от lsFusion

Tags: debian, lsfusion

Установил решение `MyCompany` на виртуальную машину (ВМ), под управлением `Debian 11 Bullseye` по этой ссылке: [Документация](https://mycompany-docs.lsfusion.org/Installation/).
При попытке зайти на сервер с хост-машины, в браузере выводит ошибку:

```
"HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error"<br>

Type: Exception Report
Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: lsfusion.gwt.client.base.exception.AppServerNotAvailableDispatchException: Application server [localhost:7652(default)] is not available. Reason: java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused)
Description: The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

В файле `/etc/lsfusion5-client/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml` менял эти параметры:

[image]

Указывал патч(в нем прописывал путь до файла `mycompany.jar`), вставлял в качестве параметров хоста IP адрес сервера (192.168.0.40) и порт (8080) (по умолчанию параметры были закомментированы и в хосте было указано "localhost", в порте было указано "7652"), но ошибка менялась на другую:

```
Type: Exception Report
Message: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: lsfusion.gwt.client.base.exception.AppServerNotAvailableDispatchException: Application server [192.168.0.40:8080(default)] is not available. Reason: java.util.zip.Zip_Exception incorrect header check
Description: The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Answer (score 1):

Любое приложение на `lsFusion` состоит из двух служб : `lsfusion5-server` и `lsfusion5-client`. Первое - это сервер приложений. Второе - это веб-сервер на базе `Apache Tomcat`, который общается с сервером приложений через Java RMI-протокол по порту, заданному в параметрах `ROOT.xml`. По-умолчанию, это 7652.

Значимая ошибка в вашем логе это :

> Application server [localhost:7652(default)] is not available. Reason: java.net.ConnectException Connection refused (Connection refused)

Она означает, что для веб-сервера сервер приложений не доступен по этому порту. Есть две основные причины, почему такое может быть :

1. Сервер приложений вообще никогда не запускался. Его можно запустить при помощи команды `systemctl start lsfusion5-server`.
2. Сервер приложений запускался, но остановился в следствие ошибки. Посмотреть ошибку можно либо при помощи команды `systemctl status lsfusion5-server`, либо в логе запуска сервера, который находится в файле `/var/log/lsfusion5-server/start.log`.

Дальше нужно анализировать логи, и устранять непосредственную причину возникающей ошибки. Ошибка может быть как в самом коде логики приложения, так и в доступности сервера базы данных, повреждении базы данных, настройках и во многом другом.